# .net core 3 jwt token configuration to deploy linux

Tags: .net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I am following [introduction to single page authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) tutorial from Microsoft.

This tutorial uses IdentityServerJwt authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

I haven't tested yet but as the tutorial says this application works fine in the local environment without doing any configuration for JSON web tokens.

this is how appsettings.Development.json file looks like:

```
"IdentityServer": {
"Key": {
"Type": "Development"
}
}
```

On [deploy to production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#deploy-to-production) section it shows how to configure azure web service, add certificate to azure and app.settings.json file for that configuration.

app.settings.json:

```
"IdentityServer": {
"Key": {
"Type": "Store",
"StoreName": "My",
"StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
"Name": "CN=MyApplication"
}
}
```

So my question is how can I configure my Linux server(ubuntu), how can I add the certificate to validate JSON web tokens and how should I configure my app.settings.json file for my Linux environment. I haven't seen any tutorial which shows that step by step.